# Simple framework XML binding with generic types

Tags: android, generics, simple-framework

I'm trying to implement a base class for binding from the following XML file.

```
<BaseClass>
    <SUCCESS>TRUE</SUCCESS>
    <MESSAGE>TEST</MESSAGE>
    <CONTENT>
        <InfoList>
            <Info>
                <MESSAGE>Test1</MESSAGE>
            </Info>
            <Info>
                <MESSAGE>Test2</MESSAGE>
            </Info>
        </InfoList>
    </CONTENT>
<BaseClass/>
```

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Serializer serializer = new Persister();
     try {
         BaseClass<InfoList> contact = serializer.read(BaseClass.class, readAsset(getAssets(), "textXml.xml"));
         Log.v("Information", contact.toString());
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

BaseClass.java

```
@Root
public class BaseClass<T> {
    @Element
    private String SUCCESS;
    @Element
    private String MESSAGE;
    @Element
    T CONTENT;

    public String getSUCCESS() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void setSUCCESS(String SUCCESS) {
        this.SUCCESS = SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getMESSAGE() {
        return MESSAGE;
    }

    public void setMESSAGE(String MESSAGE) {
        this.MESSAGE = MESSAGE;
    }

    public T getCONTENT() {
        return CONTENT;
    }

    public void setCONTENT(T CONTENT) {
        this.CONTENT = CONTENT;
    }
}
```

InfoList.java:

```
@Root
public class InfoList {

    @ElementList(type = Info.class)
    private List<Info> infoList;

    public List<Info> getInfoList() {
        return infoList;
    }

    public void setInfoList(List<Info> infoList) {
        this.infoList = infoList;
    }
}
```

Information:

```
@Root
public class Info {
    @Element
    private String MESSAGE;

    public String getMESSAGE() {
        return MESSAGE;
    }

    public void setMESSAGE(String MESSAGE) {
        this.MESSAGE = MESSAGE;
    }
}
```

The XML example is an answer of an HTTP result, and it is standard for every result except for the CONTENT part. I want to implement the class such that you can deserialise XML and bind it to the instance BaseClass<%Your class%> so that it can be generic and get rid of standard binding for every result.

When I try the code without the T type and write InfoList type to CONTENT it works fine, but each time I try the code, the deserialiser sees the T type as Object and it gives exception such that no InfoList parameter can be found in the Object class.

Comment: can u show your Serializer class

Comment: You mean Persister? Serializer is the interface provided from framework, and Persister is the class implementing Serializer also provided from framework.

Comment: I gusss u mean this http://sourceforge.net/projects/simple/?source=typ_redirect

Comment: Yes, with a dependency org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1

Comment: as far as I understand thats not possible based on  its documantation which says the "type must be provided explicitly."                                                                   http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php

Comment: Yea I guess so.. I had to extend my content class to the BaseClass.. No more final BaseClass

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu could you give the solution you found? I'm currently facing the same problem

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu i'm also having this problem as of March 2018 :) . Can you post the answer?